# Using cucumber programmatically

Tags: cucumber

I am working on transitioning our code to use cucumber programmatically, however I don't see an option to provide json for reporting.

Code Before -

```
            const cucumberPath = require.resolve(".bin/cucumber-js")
            const cucumberConfigPath = path.join(cwd, <config file path>)
            writeCucumberConfigFile(cucumberConfigPath, cucumber_config)
            execSync(
                `npx ${cucumberPath} --config ${constants.testRunnerConfigFiles.cucumberConfigFile} -f json:${reportDir}/${reportFilename}`, {
                    encoding: "utf8",
                    stdio: "inherit" }
            )
```

After trying to follow the guide for programmatic access - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/javascript_api.md

I have come up with this:

```
            const cucumberAPI = require.resolve("@cucumber/cucumber/api")
            const { loadConfiguration, loadSupport, runCucumber } = await import(cucumberAPI)
            const cucumberConfigPath = path.join(cwd, <path to config>)
            writeCucumberConfigFile(cucumberConfigPath, cucumber_config)
            const { runConfiguration } = await loadConfiguration({ file: constants.testRunnerConfigFiles.cucumberConfigFile })
            const support = await loadSupport(runConfiguration)
            await runCucumber({ ...runConfiguration, support })
```

Execution works fine, the only missing thing is the json which we were able to pass in earlier version and are not able to pass now. I checked the code base, but couldn't find a parameter for that. Any idea how I can send a json's path to generate a JSON-report files, this will then be used by https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this -

```
        const { runConfiguration } = await loadConfiguration({ 
            file: <path to config>,
            provided: {
                format: [
                    `json:<path to json>`
                ]
            }
        })
```

We just need to provide the path to json like this in loadConfigurations.